# MultipleChoiceField create multiple objects

Tags: python, django, algorithm, python-3.x, django-1.10

I use **MultipleChoiceField** in my form. I want to add all selected values to database, but next code which I use add only last value which user select. I tried in my view create multiple number objects. Where I did mistake?

**models.py:**

```
class Requirement(models.Model):
    code = models.UUIDField(_('Code'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    symbol = models.CharField(_('Symbol'), max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    symbol= forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES,)

    class Meta:
        model = Requirement
        fields = ('symbol',)


REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES = (
    ('A', 'Name A'),
    ('B', 'Name B'),
    ('C', 'Name C'),
)
```

**views.py:**

```
def requirement_add(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            list = dict(REQUIREMENTS_CHOICES) # {'C': 'Name C', 'A': 'Name A', 'B': 'Name B'}
            symbols = form.cleaned_data.get('symbol') # ['A', 'B', 'C']
            requirement = form.save(commit=False)
            for symbol in symbols:
                requirement.symbol = symbol
                requirement.name = list[symbol]
                requirement.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            requirements = Requirement.objects.filter()
            context = {requirement': requirement, 'requirements': requirements}
            data['html_requirement'] = render_to_string('project/requirement_list.html', context)
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = AddForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_requirement_form'] = render_to_string('project/requirement_add.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `requirement.pk = None` so that every call to `save` will insert a new row in the database :

```
for symbol in symbols:
    requirement.symbol = symbol
    requirement.name = group_requirement_list[symbol]
    requirement.pk = None
    requirement.save()
```

See the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert.

Edit:

**Explanation** : in the first iteration of this loop `requirement.save()` will insert a new row in the database as you would expect. But after that `requirement` will have the primary key of the new row and Django will try to update it instead of creating a new one.

**Alternative solution** : you could avoid all of this if you put `requirement = form.save(commit=False)` in the for loop like this :

```
symbols = form.cleaned_data.get('symbol') # ['A', 'B', 'C']
for symbol in symbols:
    requirement = form.save(commit=False)
    requirement.symbol = symbol
    requirement.name = group_requirement_list[symbol]
    requirement.save()
```

Comment: Thank you! `requirement.pk = None` works for me but I dont understand why it works xD Can you explain little bit? As you can see code field is my pk, also I use default=uuid.uuid4. So I thought it will create pk automatically. Also thanks for the link.

Comment: You're welcome ! I added an explanation and an alternative solution.